# Visual Studio Code fails to use a library

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have project which I need to modify for a task and that runs a terminal with the help of a .jar file. I can run the very same Code on an IDE like Eclipse, but not VSC.
This is the error is get:
The jar files for this project are:

`text-io-3.4.0.jar`, `slf4j-api-2.0.0-alpha5.jar` and `slf4j-nop-2.0.0-alpha5.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/console/ConsoleReader
        at org.beryx.textio.jline.JLineTextTerminalProvider.getTextTerminal(JLineTextTerminalProvider.java:28)
        at org.beryx.textio.TextIoFactory$Holder.getDefaultTerminal(TextIoFactory.java:95)
        at org.beryx.textio.TextIoFactory$Holder.<init>(TextIoFactory.java:65)
        at org.beryx.textio.TextIoFactory$Holder.<clinit>(TextIoFactory.java:54)
        at org.beryx.textio.TextIoFactory.getTextIO(TextIoFactory.java:111)
        at ch.zhaw.catan.Catan.run(Catan.java:19)
        at ch.zhaw.catan.Catan.main(Catan.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.console.ConsoleReader
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 7 more
```

I assume it's about configurations. The path to the library is set within the project. I don't see the error, my professor doesn't use VSC.
What can I do to fix this? Do I need to provide more data? I could upload the files if needed.

-edit
here's a link to the dummy.java and the jar files
https://github.com/dangdung87/test

as for the lines causing the error:

```
private void run() {
    TextIO textIO = TextIoFactory.getTextIO();
    TextTerminal<?> textTerminal = textIO.getTextTerminal();
```

Comment: You may post code snippets that can reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the textio lib needs the jline library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jline/jline/2.14.6).

Download the jar and add it to the dependencies of the project.

We had the same problem with the catan project ;)